# Vue JS 3 Class Binding Does not Apply

Tags: vuejs3

In attempting to apply an example from the [Vue 3 guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#object-syntax) on class and style bindings, I'm unable to get class binding to work.

```js
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Vue version: ' + Vue.version,
      classObj: {
        active: true,
        'text-danger': false
      }
    }
  }
}
Vue.createApp(App).mount('#result')
```

```css
.active {
  color: #00FF00;
}

.text-danger {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.16"></script>

<div id="result" class="static" :class="classObj">{{ message }} <br> {{ classObj }}</div>
```

It appears that Vue is loading and the Vue app is returning `classObj` properly `{ "active": true, "text-danger": false }`. Note that I'm printing the value of `classObj` to the DOM merely to inspect its value.

I have tried:

- applying the `classObj` payload directly in the div statement with the same outcome (placing the object `{ "active": true, "text-danger": false }` as the class attribute in the `<div>`.
- several different CDN sources and several different Vue 3 build versions.
- similar examples using Vue 2 with success, but have not been able to apply the binding (at all) in Vue 3.

Comment: just make a template for it ans it should work

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  From the docs: "Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes. Instead, use a v-bind directive:"  (https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/template-syntax.html#interpolations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is you are trying to bind to attributes to the top level element that Vue instance is mounted to. Try move the reactive component to a child node:

```js
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Vue version: ' + Vue.version,
      classObj: {
        active: true,
        'text-danger': false
      }
    }
  }
}
Vue.createApp(App).mount('#result')
```

```css
.active {
  color: #00FF00;
}

.text-danger {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.16"></script>

<div id="result">
  <div class="static" :class="classObj">{{ message }} <br> {{ classObj }}</div>
</div>
```